# Make set of two services in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a Banquet Hall Bookings project. In which,

I've a table `tblServices`:

```
serID   serName     serStatus
-----   ---------   ---------
1       Service1    Available
2       Service2    Available
3       Service3    Available
4       Service4    Available
5       Service5    Available
```

I'm trying to access them as set of two services in one row like:

```
serName     serStatus   serName2    serStatus2
--------    ---------   --------    ---------
Service1    Available   Service2    Available
Service3    Available   Service4    Available
Service5    Available
```

A try is:

```
SELECT serName,serStatus,serName2,serStatus2 FROM tblServices WHERE ???
```

How to I can solve this problem?

Help will be really appreciated!

### Edit:

I've stored a basic services and extra services in one table so the extra service name is concatenated with `:extra`. Therefore, I can't get the last row using below answer.

```
serID   serName           serStatus
-----   --------------    ---------
1       Service1          Available
2       Service2          Available
3       Service3          Available
4       Service4          Available
5       Service5:extra    Available
6       Service6:extra    Available
7       Service7:extra    Available
8       Service8:extra    Available
```

Now below is a query that will select only extra services from above table as:

```
SELECT serID, LEFT(serName, CHARINDEX(':', t.serName + ':') - 1) AS serName, serStatus
FROM dbo.tblService AS t
WHERE t.serName LIKE '%:%'
```

Table is:

```
serID   serName     serStatus
-----   --------    ---------
5       Service5    Available
6       Service6    Available
7       Service7    Available
8       Service8    Available
```

How I can use the this query with below answer's query?

Comment: self join, odd vs even id's.

Comment: Why is that a part of your data query? This is pure data presentation

Comment: Such formatting should be done at the application level, not through a query (although it is possible in a query).

Comment: See my update query for the new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d24b4/6)**

```
SELECT s1.serName ,  s1.serStatus,
       s2.serName as serName2,  s2.serStatus  serStatus2
FROM service s1
LEFT JOIN service s2
  ON s1.serID = s2.serID-1
WHERE s1.serID % 2 = 1
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. But last row is not retrieved.

Comment: Did you saw the sql demo? is working there. What you mean isnt retrieved?

Comment: My `serName` is stored as `service5:extra` that is not retrieved.

Comment: that isnt what you show in your sample data. what is `:extra` feel free to update the sql demo and send me the link replicating the problem

Comment: Your answer is good I gave you +1. But I've stored a basic services and extra services in one table so the extra service name is concatenated with `:extra`.

Comment: dont know what that mean, and again that is not what you show in your sample data :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you have gaps in your ID's? If yes @Juan Carlos Oropeza solution will not work. Try this one:

```
select
    substring([0], 1, 100), substring([0], 101, 100), substring([1], 1, 100), substring([1], 101, 100)
from (
    select
        cast(serName as char(100)) + cast(serStatus as char(100)) ser, (row_number()over(order by serID) - 1) / 2 r1, (row_number()over(order by serID) - 1) % 2 r2
    from 
        myTable
) t
pivot (
    max(ser) for r2 in([0],[1])
) p
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1 and I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

If MS SQL 2012 and up, use LAG/LEAD can easily get this return, if serID has gap, use row_number instead.

```
CREATE TABLE tblServices
(SerID int NOT NULL,
serName varchar(20),
serStatus varchar(20)
)

INSERT tblServices (serID, serName, serStatus)
values(1,'Service1','Available')
INSERT tblServices (serID, serName, serStatus)
values(2,'Service2','Available')
INSERT tblServices (serID, serName, serStatus)
values(3,'Service3','Available')
INSERT tblServices (serID, serName, serStatus)
values(4,'Service4','Available')
INSERT tblServices (serID, serName, serStatus)
values(5,'Service5:extra','Available')

SELECT * FROM
(
  select serID, serName, serStatus, LEAD(serName) OVER (ORDER BY serID ASC) AS SerName2, LEAD(serStatus) OVER (ORDER BY serID ASC) AS SerStatus2
FROM tblServices
) AS Temp
where serID %2 <>0
```

[image]

updated query for new changes, you can remove :extra easily using substring

```
SELECT * FROM
(
select SerID, serName,serStatus, LEAD(serName) OVER (ORDER BY serID ASC)     AS SerName2, LEAD(serStatus) OVER (ORDER BY serID ASC) AS SerStatus2
FROM tblServices
) AS Temp
where serID %2 = 1
and serName LIKE '%:%'
```

[image]

tblServices data, and I run the script again without any problem on MS SQL 2012
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1 and I've edited my question.

Comment: Its showing errors under `tblServices` and columns.

Comment: It is works for me, could you show us what is the error? BTW, are you MS SQL 2012 and up?

Comment: yeh.. I'm using MS SQL 2014